# Unexpected results in Node.js implementing flow control with Series function (pattern?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm attempting to implement a series function for flow control purposes but getting unexpected results. I need to check for the existence of a file, as the result a shell cmd initiated by Node, over the course of say 5000 ms. Using Mixu's [Node book](http://book.mixu.net/ch7.html) I am utilizing a series function for sequential execution (section 7.2.1). Per the Node book, this pattern would be appropriate if you needed one result to feed into another, but that does not seem to be the case as the `final()` is being executed before any of the callbacks from the argument functions return.

Below should be all the code needed to reproduce what I am seeing.

**Expected output**: (assume the file being checked for was created in < 1000ms)

> 1347312844082
>   true
>   1347312845082
>   true
>   1347312846083
>   true
>   1347312847082
>   true
>   1347312848082
>   true
>   true <-- last true result of console.log() in last param function of series function.

**Actual output**:

> 1347312844082
>   1347312845082
>   1347312846083
>   1347312847082
>   1347312848082
>   false <-- last param function of series function being evaluated before series args callbacks.
>   true
>   true
>   true
>   true
>   true

I'm *guessing* the callbacks from my sleep functions (which contain the `fs.check` calls)

- are being pushed back as a result of the `args` param of the series function all being invoked by slice.call(arguments)
- then shifting to the last function,
- and finally handling the callbacks.

But this seems contradictory as to what is the described behavior in the Node book.

*Note*: I'm trying to avoid regressing back into sync calls (`fs.existsSync`) in an attempt to break my brain and maybe finally "get it" when it comes to Node/async programming.

```
    var outputFile = 'C:\\Some\\Valid\\Path\\foo.txt';
    var successCheck = false;
    series([
            sleep(1000, function () {
                printTime();
                fs.exists(outputFile, function (exists) {
                    console.log(exists);
                    successCheck = exists;
                });
            }),
            /* middle three deleted for brevity */
            sleep(1000, function () {
                printTime();
                fs.exists(outputFile, function (exists) {
                    console.log(exists);
                    successCheck = exists;
                });
            }),

            sleep(1000, function () {
                printTime();
                fs.exists(outputFile, function (exists) {
                    console.log(exists);
                    successCheck = exists;
                });
            })
            ], function() {
                console.log(successCheck);
        });


    function sleep (msInterval, callback) {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        while(new Date().getTime() < now + msInterval) {
      // do nothing
        }
        callback();
    }

    function series (callbacks, last)  {
        var results = [];
        function next() {
            var callback = callbacks.shift();
            if(callback) {
                callback(function() {
                    results.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
                    next();
                });
            } else {
                last(results);
            }
        }

        next();
    }

    function printTime () { var now = new Date().getTime(); console.log(now); }
```

Comment: Aside: `Date.now()` gives you the current time in milliseconds (since the epoch), which is much easier to type than `new Date().getTime()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several problems with your code.  First and foremost, your approach to "sleep" is completely broken.

JavaScript (and thus Node) is a single-threaded, event-driven language.  If you do anything that blocks, you block your entire program.

Your `sleep` function blocks the entire program by spinning until `msInterval` milliseconds pass.

## Here's exactly what is happening:

- Start by setting some variables.
- There is a call to `series`.  In order to pass it arguments, we must evaluate those arguments.
- `sleep` is invoked on the next line.
- `sleep` spins for 1000 ms.
- `sleep` invokes its `callback`.
- The callback prints stuff to the console, issues an asynchronous I/O request, and returns.
- `sleep` returns *undefined*.
- The next call to `sleep` is invoked; the last 5 steps are repeated.
- ...after 5 seconds, all calls to `sleep` have completed.  You now have an Array that looks like this:

  ```
  [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
  ```

  since `sleep` doesn't return anything.
- Now `series` can be invoked with the arguments an array of *undefined*s and a Function.
- `results` is instantiated.
- `next` is invoked.
- The first *undefined* from the array is shifted off.
- Since *undefined* is falsy, jump to the `else` branch.
- Call `last` with an empty array. (We never put anything in `results`)
- The `last` callback prints `successCheck`, which is `false`, and returns.
- At this point, synchronous code has completed.
- JavaScript starts the next iteration of the event loop.  The I/O requests you issued earlier are probably complete by this point, so the `fs.exists` callbacks are invoked in the order they completed (which is probably, but not necessarily the order they were issued).
- The callbacks print to the console and set `successCheck` (which is never actually read again).
- The program ends.

## How to fix it

Never, ever, ever spin in a `while` loop.  You could rewrite `sleep` like this:

```
function sleep(ms, cb) {
    return function(done) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            cb(done);
        }, ms);
    }
}
```

Here, we return a function that will be invoked later.  This way, the array that gets passed to `series` is filled with the inner `sleep` function.  When you call this `sleep`, **nothing has actually happened yet**.

When `series` calls the first array element, it is actually invoking the returned anonymous function, where we've closed over the `ms` and `cb` that were originally passed to the `sleep` call.  The function sets a timeout for `ms` milliseconds.  What that expires, the innermost anonymous function is invoked, which calls `cb`.  It passes the `done` function as its argument, which is actually the anonymous function from `series`' `next` that pushes onto `results` and calls `next`.

Because the next step of your series isn't started until the previous step indicates it's done, you have to call the `done` callback from the step's function:

```
sleep(1000, function (done) {
    printTime();
    fs.exists(outputFile, function (exists) {
        console.log(exists);
        successCheck = exists;
        done();
    });
});
```

## Change your approach

Of course, the way you really want to solve the problem ("How do I do something after this file has been created?") is not by polling `fs.exists`.

Instead, use filesystem change notifications!  [`fs.watch`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) allows you to listen for changes to files or folders.

```
var watcher = fs.watch('C:\\Some\\Valid\\Path\\', function(e, filename) {
    if (filename == 'foo.txt') {
        // success!
        watcher.close(); // stop watching for changes
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification (especially on my Sleep implementation)